# Thin ITX board with Broadwell support

Tags: motherboard, thin-mini-itx

I am looking to improve my thin system (Haswell on H81) in the graphic department so Broadwell i5-5675C with its Iris seems to be a good choice. Sadly, I can't find any **thin** mini-ITX board to support it (built on H97 or Z97). Gigabyte [boasts GA-H97TN](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=5290#ov), however after almost a year of it I am convinced this product doesn't exist — it was neither sold nor tested anywhere.

The question is: Is there any **thin** mini-ITX board supporting Broadwell (LGA1150) that can be actually bought?

Please pay attention to the thin part: I'm asking about a board using an external 19V laptop-style power brick, not a regular ATX PSU. I am aware of pico-PSUs, but that's also out of scope.

Comment: There are some LGA1150 thin mini-ITX boards but they are older chipsets. You need specifically the H97 or Z97 chipset?

Comment: @SSumner Yes, I wasn't very clear but I already have LGA1550 thin-itx system (GA-H81TN) and I'm loving it. The only problem is that Broadwells are the only CPUs which combine top CPU performance with decent onboard GPU.